# Can we use custom cards to pay using ApplePay?

Tags: ios, integration, applepay

I'm aware that, with ApplePay one can pay through [various banks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204916) cards linked into Apple Pay, my question is, if there's a kind of big Mall in a particular city and they're providing their own card, in which they can add money to purchase things inside that Mall, that card can be useful (to pay) against the shopping using ApplePay? Is this possible?

I've not enough knowledge on ApplePay but I'm quite sure that it's linked to a user's bank account. So at any point of time if they're paying money, it'll be deducted from their bank account. Would it be accomplish for that particular Mall?

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about becoming an Apple Pay card provider

Comment: The mall would have to be a bank and sign up with Apple to be a card provider

Comment: @Paulw11, As per [this](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf) link, see Common Questions & Answer's section part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulw11 commented,

> The mall would have to be a bank and sign up with Apple to be a card provider.